# How to update a TextView after an API response with Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, user-interface, retrofit2

I am completely new to Kotlin, Coroutines and API calls, and I am trying to make an app based on [this API](https://www.freetogame.com/api-doc).

My intention is to display the information of a game in my `MainActivity`, so I need ot fill some `TextView` for that purpose.

My API call and response system works perfectly well: the responses are OK and there are no errors, but the call is made using Kotlin's coroutines which won't let me update my UI after getting the response.

For the sake of simplicity, I am only attaching my **MainActivity** code, which is the source of the problem.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var b: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        b = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        listAllGames()
    }

    private fun listAllGames() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val call = getRetrofit().create(APIService::class.java).listAllGames("")
            val games = call.body()
            runOnUiThread {
                if (call.isSuccessful) {
                    b.gameTitle.text = games?.get(0)?.title ?: "Dummy"
                    b.gameDesc.text = games?.get(0)?.short_description ?: "Dummy"
                    b.gameGenre.text = games?.get(0)?.genre ?: "Dummy"
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d("mydebug", "call unsuccessful")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.freetogame.com/api/games/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

Concretely, the `listAllGames()` method is the problem here: the app will build successfully, if a breakpoint is added inside the `if (call.isSuccessful)` block, it'll show the data correctly; but when running the app the display will be left blank forever.

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use view binding you need to pass the inflated view from the binding to the `setContentView` method. Otherwise you inflate the view with the binding but display the XML layout without the binding.

Check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities):

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

(Source: [Android Developer documentation - " View Binding   Part of Android Jetpack."](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding))

Change your `onCreate` method as followed:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    b = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(b.root)
    listAllGames()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer explains your problems with your view, but you also have some issues with the coroutine.

- You should use `lifecycleScope` instead of creating a new scope. `lifecycleScope` will automatically cancel itself to avoid leaking the Activity if the activity is destroyed, such as during a screen rotation.
- You should use Retrofit's `call.await()` suspend function instead of directly blocking a thread and having to specify a dispatcher. This also lets you leave things on the main dispatcher and directly update UI without having to use `runOnUiThread`.

```
    private fun listAllGames() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val call = getRetrofit().create(APIService::class.java).listAllGames("")
            try { 
                val games = call.await()
                b.gameTitle.text = games?.get(0)?.title ?: "Dummy"
                b.gameDesc.text = games?.get(0)?.short_description ?: "Dummy"
                b.gameGenre.text = games?.get(0)?.genre ?: "Dummy"
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d("mydebug", "call unsuccessful", e)
            }
        }
    }
```

And actually, you should move API calls like this into a ViewModel so they can keep running during a screen rotation. If you do that, the function in the ViewModel should update a LiveData or SharedFlow instead of UI elements. Then your Activity can observe for changes. If the call is started and the screen is rotated, the API call will keep running and still publish its changes to the new Activity's UI without having to restart.

Comment: Everything's working fine but the compiler complains about "Unresolved reference". I am using Retrofit2 v.2.9.0

Comment: Complains about which piece of code?

Comment: Complains about async()!

Comment: Do you mean `await()`?  It is an extension function. So you need to import it separately from the Call class.